# Issue in if/else block objective-c iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am using the below code for assigning values to my labels and imageviews but its not working properly. I am not getting the issue

```
if ([child11 length] != 0) {
    [childButton1 setAlpha:1];
    [childButton2 setAlpha:0];
    [childButton3 setAlpha:0];
    [childButton4 setAlpha:0];
    [childButton5 setAlpha:0];
    [childButton6 setAlpha:0];
    //label1.text = child11;
    NSLog(@"here we are");

    if ([child11image isEqualToString:@"Fajar"]) {
        image1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Blue-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
        NSLog(@"child11image::: %@", child11image);
        label1.text = child11;
    } else if ([child11image isEqualToString:@"Zuhr"]) {
        image1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Orange-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
        label1.text = child11;
    } else if ([child11image isEqualToString:@"Asr"]) {
        image1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pink-Jaanamaz-Large"]];
        label1.text = child11;
        NSLog(@"child11image::: %@", child11image);
    } else if ([child11image isEqualToString:@"Maghrib"]) {
        image1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Green-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
        label1.text = child11;
    } else if ([child11image isEqualToString:@"Isha"]) {
        image1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Purple-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
        label1.text = child11;
    }
} else if ([child22 length] != 0){
    [childButton1 setAlpha:1];
    [childButton2 setAlpha:1];
    [childButton3 setAlpha:0];
    [childButton4 setAlpha:0];
    [childButton5 setAlpha:0];
    [childButton6 setAlpha:0];  
    label2.text = child22;

    if ([child22image isEqualToString:@"Fajar"]) {
        image2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Blue-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child22image isEqualToString:@"Zuhr"]) {
        image2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Orange-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child22image isEqualToString:@"Asr"]) {
        image2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pink-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child22image isEqualToString:@"Maghrib"]) {
        image2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Green-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child22image isEqualToString:@"Isha"]) {
        image2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Purple-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    }
} else if ([child33 length] != 0){
    [childButton1 setAlpha:1];
    [childButton2 setAlpha:1];
    [childButton3 setAlpha:1];
    [childButton4 setAlpha:0];
    [childButton5 setAlpha:0];
    [childButton6 setAlpha:0];

    label3.text = child33;

    if ([child33image isEqualToString:@"Fajar"]) {
        image3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Blue-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child33image isEqualToString:@"Zuhr"]) {
        image3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Orange-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child33image isEqualToString:@"Asr"]) {
        image3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pink-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child33image isEqualToString:@"Maghrib"]) {
        image3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Green-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child33image isEqualToString:@"Isha"]) {
        image3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Purple-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    }
} else if ([child44 length] != 0) {
    [childButton1 setAlpha:1];
    [childButton2 setAlpha:1];
    [childButton3 setAlpha:1];
    [childButton4 setAlpha:1];
    [childButton5 setAlpha:0];
    [childButton6 setAlpha:0];

    label4.text = child44;

    if ([child44image isEqualToString:@"Fajar"]) {
        image4 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Blue-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child44image isEqualToString:@"Zuhr"]) {
        image4 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Orange-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child44image isEqualToString:@"Asr"]) {
        image4 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pink-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child44image isEqualToString:@"Maghrib"]) {
        image4 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Green-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child44image isEqualToString:@"Isha"]) {
        image4 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Purple-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    }
} else if ([child55 length] != 0) {
    [childButton1 setAlpha:1];
    [childButton2 setAlpha:1];
    [childButton3 setAlpha:1];
    [childButton4 setAlpha:1];
    [childButton5 setAlpha:1];
    [childButton6 setAlpha:0];

    label5.text = child55;

    if ([child55image isEqualToString:@"Fajar"]) {
        image5 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Blue-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child55image isEqualToString:@"Zuhr"]) {
        image5 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Orange-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child55image isEqualToString:@"Asr"]) {
        image5 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pink-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child55image isEqualToString:@"Maghrib"]) {
        image5 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Green-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child55image isEqualToString:@"Isha"]) {
        image5 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Purple-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    }
} else if ([child66 length] != 0) {
    [childButton1 setAlpha:1];
    [childButton2 setAlpha:1];
    [childButton3 setAlpha:1];
    [childButton4 setAlpha:1];
    [childButton5 setAlpha:1];
    [childButton6 setAlpha:1];

    label6.text = child66;

    if ([child66image isEqualToString:@"Fajar"]) {
        image6 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Blue-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child66image isEqualToString:@"Zuhr"]) {
        image6 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Orange-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child66image isEqualToString:@"Asr"]) {
        image6 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pink-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child66image isEqualToString:@"Maghrib"]) {
        image6 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Green-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child66image isEqualToString:@"Isha"]) {
        image6 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Purple-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    }
} else ([child11 length] == 0) {
    [childButton1 setAlpha:0];
    [childButton2 setAlpha:0];
    [childButton3 setAlpha:0];
    [childButton4 setAlpha:0];
    [childButton5 setAlpha:0];
    [childButton6 setAlpha:0];
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you tell us what the desired and actual outcomes are? It would help in determining what is going wrong here.

Comment: Also... this is awful code! :D

Comment: @jtbandes what exactly is wrong with it? Don't just criticise, teach. :)

Comment: Trying to assign the values and images to the labels and uiiamgeviews

Comment: @ThomasClayson: Yes, yes... well, for starters, it's nearly the same block of code copy/pasted 6 times! Could definitely be refactored and simplified.

Comment: @jtbandes absolutely :) Infact there's about 2 lines of code in there which are repeated many times. This can be cut down. There's usually no need to have the same line of code more than once!

Comment: Use a switch-statement and for-loops or NSDictionaries instead. I agree, this code looks horrible.

Comment: @iError: The reason why people voted this down, is because you are not explaining what is wrong, you're just saying 'it's not working' and pasting in your code. That is not the StackOverflow way of asking a question. Welcome to the community, I suggest you read the FAQ, that way you can avoid getting all the down votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what the actual problem is but the if statement has to be wrong.  The first two conditions are

```
if ([child11 length] == 0)
{
    // do stuff
}
else if ([child11 length] != 0)
{
    // do stuff
}
else  // nothing else matters
```

You will always go through one of the first two cases because `(x == 0 || x != 0) == true` by definition.  All of the stuff to do with child22, child33 etc never gets done.

Comment: I have changed the code, the first if part if ([child11 length] == 0) has been assigned as else at the end.

Answer (score 1):

i think this is what you mean

```
if ([child11 length] != 0){
    [childButton1 setAlpha:1]; [childButton2 setAlpha:0]; [childButton3 setAlpha:0]; [childButton4 setAlpha:0];
    [childButton5 setAlpha:0]; [childButton6 setAlpha:0];
    label1.text = child11;
    if ([child11image isEqualToString:@"Fajar"]) {
        image1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Blue-Jaanamaz-Small"]];           
    } else if ([child11image isEqualToString:@"Zuhr"]) {
        image1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Orange-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child11image isEqualToString:@"Asr"]) {
        image1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pink-Jaanamaz-Large"]];
    } else if ([child11image isEqualToString:@"Maghrib"]) {
        image1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Green-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child11image isEqualToString:@"Isha"]) {
        image1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Purple-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    }
} else if ([child22 length] != 0){
    [childButton1 setAlpha:1]; [childButton2 setAlpha:1]; [childButton3 setAlpha:0]; [childButton4 setAlpha:0];
    [childButton5 setAlpha:0]; [childButton6 setAlpha:0];
    label2.text = child22;

    if ([child22image isEqualToString:@"Fajar"]) {
        image2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Blue-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child22image isEqualToString:@"Zuhr"]) {
        image2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Orange-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child22image isEqualToString:@"Asr"]) {
        image2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pink-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child22image isEqualToString:@"Maghrib"]) {
        image2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Green-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child22image isEqualToString:@"Isha"]) {
        image2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Purple-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    }
} else if ([child33 length] != 0){
    [childButton1 setAlpha:1]; [childButton2 setAlpha:1]; [childButton3 setAlpha:1]; [childButton4 setAlpha:0];
    [childButton5 setAlpha:0]; [childButton6 setAlpha:0];
    label3.text = child33;

    if ([child33image isEqualToString:@"Fajar"]) {
        image3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Blue-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child33image isEqualToString:@"Zuhr"]) {
        image3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Orange-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child33image isEqualToString:@"Asr"]) {
        image3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pink-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child33image isEqualToString:@"Maghrib"]) {
        image3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Green-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child33image isEqualToString:@"Isha"]) {
        image3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Purple-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    }
} else if ([child44 length] != 0){
    [childButton1 setAlpha:1]; [childButton2 setAlpha:1]; [childButton3 setAlpha:1]; [childButton4 setAlpha:1];
    [childButton5 setAlpha:0]; [childButton6 setAlpha:0];
    label4.text = child44;

    if ([child44image isEqualToString:@"Fajar"]) {
        image4 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Blue-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child44image isEqualToString:@"Zuhr"]) {
        image4 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Orange-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child44image isEqualToString:@"Asr"]) {
        image4 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pink-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child44image isEqualToString:@"Maghrib"]) {
        image4 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Green-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child44image isEqualToString:@"Isha"]) {
        image4 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Purple-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    }
} else if ([child55 length] != 0){
    [childButton1 setAlpha:1]; [childButton2 setAlpha:1]; [childButton3 setAlpha:1]; [childButton4 setAlpha:1];
    [childButton5 setAlpha:1]; [childButton6 setAlpha:0];
    label5.text = child55;

    if ([child55image isEqualToString:@"Fajar"]) {
        image5 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Blue-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child55image isEqualToString:@"Zuhr"]) {
        image5 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Orange-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child55image isEqualToString:@"Asr"]) {
        image5 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pink-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child55image isEqualToString:@"Maghrib"]) {
        image5 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Green-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child55image isEqualToString:@"Isha"]) {
        image5 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Purple-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    }
} else if ([child66 length] != 0){
    [childButton1 setAlpha:1]; [childButton2 setAlpha:1]; [childButton3 setAlpha:1]; [childButton4 setAlpha:1];
    [childButton5 setAlpha:1]; [childButton6 setAlpha:1];
    label6.text = child66;

    if ([child66image isEqualToString:@"Fajar"]) {
        image6 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Blue-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child66image isEqualToString:@"Zuhr"]) {
        image6 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Orange-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child66image isEqualToString:@"Asr"]) {
        image6 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pink-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child66image isEqualToString:@"Maghrib"]) {
        image6 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Green-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    } else if ([child66image isEqualToString:@"Isha"]) {
        image6 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Purple-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
    }
} else {
    [childButton1 setAlpha:0]; [childButton2 setAlpha:0]; [childButton3 setAlpha:0]; [childButton4 setAlpha:0];
    [childButton5 setAlpha:0]; [childButton6 setAlpha:0];
}
```

The issue i found this code is if a condition occur like  `if ([child11 length] == 0)` and  `if ([child11 length] !=0)` the `childButton1`, `childButton2`  `setAlpha:` will be `1`. I think you have to do the `childButton1 setAlpha` as `0` and `childButton2  setAlpha` as `1` if the above condition occures. I dont know what you exactly need

And one thing. *Don't write codes just like this. Use switch cases and enumes to improve the code readability and performance.*  happy coding.

Comment: Actually what I was trying to do is, that is first condition does not met then second condition should be done, if second does not met then third should be done. As I was trying that if child11 has some value in it then do that whatever is in first condition, now it has done next time when  child22 will have a value then do the second condition stuff done. I dont know how to achieve this. Child11, child22 .... these are values saved in NSUserDefaults ... can you help me with that

Answer (score 0):

If `[child11 length] != 0` you will never reach the other else-if checks. (I am guessing `child11` and `child22` can be non empty.

And you must improve your code! Start by learning examples of basic iphone apps spread all over the network.